# Three.JS Orbit Controls setAzimuthalAngle setPolarAngle

Tags: three.js

*Edit Solved

**Goal**

User

- Modify radius with scroll wheel
- Modify azimuthalangle with holding mouse down and moving mouse
- Modify polorangle with holding mouse down and moving mouse

Code

- Modify Center Point,
- Modify radius,
- Modify azimuthalangle
- Modify polarAngle
- Read Current radius (As user may have changed it)
- Read Current azimuthalangle (As user may have changed it)
- Read Current polarAngle (As user may have changed it)

**What I tried**

- Added Orbit controls [1]
- Added Code from [2] to orbit controls, setPolarAngle, and setAzimuthalAngle and all code needed into [1].

  - Added RadiusOverride to forceUpdate from [2], and maped a funtion

    ```
     if (radiusOverRide != undefined && radiusOverRide != null) {
        radius = radiusOverRide;
    }
    else {
        radius = offset.length() * scale;
    }
    ```

    this.setRadius = function (radius) {
    this.forceUpdate(radius);
    };

**Results**

The User can currently zoom, and azimuthalangle, and polorangle

The Code Can set the location

```
controls.target.set(x,y,z)
```

The code can set Both Angles

```
controls.setPolarAngle(a)
controls.setAzimuthalAngle(b);
```

The Code can read Both Angles with

```
controls.getAzimuthalAngle()
controls.getPolarAngle()
```

The Code can Set the Radius with

```
controls.setRadius(a)
```

[1] https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js

[2] https://gist.github.com/superguigui/315d5d9b13da1b3cbdf9

Edit***

The issues I was having before, have vansished, I added the minor changes I had to to finsh it out. This is solved